# \lstinline: color of "#pragma"

Tags: listings, color

I am trying to use `\lstinline` but it does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{color, listings}

\lstset
{
    language=C,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
}

\lstset{language={[x86masm]Assembler}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language = C]            
#pragma pack(1)
    \end{lstlisting}

    Das \lstinline!#pragma pack(1)! dient dazu...

\end{document}
```

In `lstliting` #pragma is correctly shown in blue color but with `\lstinline` it stays black. What is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) as always on this site, please provide a full minimal example including document class, premable, sample document body. That makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: @daleif (1) Thank you, (2) changed that :)

Comment: `\lstinline` still needs to be told the language in order to highlight correctly, just like you have done with `lstlisting`: `\lstinline[language=C]!#pragma pack(1)!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the last global (document-level) setting of `language` was `{[x86masm]Assembler}`, all `listings` package code commands/environments use this unless another language is specified on a per-listing basis.

Use `\lstinline[language=C]!#pragma pack(1)!` to use the highlighting rules for the `C` language for this particular piece of inline code.

Alternatively, if most of the code in the document is C code, remove the line `\lstset{language={[x86masm]Assembler}}` and use local language overrides for `language={[x86masm]Assembler}` as needed.